# Drawing a chart over a sum of two columns in Dynamics CRM

Tags: charts, dynamics-crm-2011

I'd like to draw a line chart based on two columns - let's call the regarded fields `cats` and `dogs`. I know I could create a third field called `animals` and populate it but that seems to me as an ugly workaround.

I'm pretty sure there's no way to achieve that via the GUI so I'm hoping that editing the produced XML will open that possibility. As far I could understand [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3669802/concatenated-calculated-columns-in-dynamics-crm-view), it's not possible but since it's old, I'm hoping that it's become possible since then.

Any luck on this one?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It's a bit unclear exactly what you are going for with this question.  This is an excellent blog on how to modify your chart's fetchxml to extend the crm chart capabilities (and it may or may not answer your question depending on exactly what you mean by "draw a line based on two columns"): https://crmchartguy.wordpress.com/2015/06/21/compare-this-year-to-last-year-with-a-dynamics-crm-chart/